# 'killed' error with python gzip on ubuntu

Tags: python, gzip

I am getting a killed error when running a python script. I will post the code below. My first debugging step was to look at the /var/log/syslog file to see whether there are any memory issues reported, but I could not find anything related to the killed event. 
So I run my code again using the python -m trace --trace flags. This clearly points to the gzip library as the last lines are

```
...
gzip.py(271):         self.offset += size
gzip.py(272):         return chunk
 --- modulename: gzip, funcname: read
gzip.py(242):         self._check_closed()
 --- modulename: gzip, funcname: _check_closed
gzip.py(154):         if self.closed:
 --- modulename: gzip, funcname: closed
gzip.py(362):         return self.fileobj is None
gzip.py(243):         if self.mode != READ:
gzip.py(247):         if self.extrasize <= 0 and self.fileobj is None:
gzip.py(250):         readsize = 1024
gzip.py(251):         if size < 0:        # get the whole thing
gzip.py(259):             try:
gzip.py(260):                 while size > self.extrasize:
gzip.py(261):                     self._read(readsize)
 --- modulename: gzip, funcname: _read
gzip.py(279):         if self.fileobj is None:
gzip.py(282):         if self._new_member:
gzip.py(301):         buf = self.fileobj.read(size)
Killed
```

I don't have much experience with this, so I don't quite know why the read command would fail like this.
Another point I noticed is that the code now fails when reading files which it processed without trouble before, so its not a problem with the code itself, but it seems a resource issue?

Here is the code

```
def fill_pubmed_papers_table(list_of_files):
    for i, f in enumerate(list_of_files):
        print "read file %d names %s" % (i, f)
        inF = gzip.open(f, 'rb')
        tree = ET.parse(inF)
        inF.close()
        root = tree.getroot()
        papers = root.findall('PubmedArticle')
        print "number of papers = ", len(papers)
        # we don't need anything from root anymore
        root.clear()
        for citation in papers:
            write_to_db(citation)
        # If I do not release memory here I get segfault on the linux server
        del papers
    return
```

EDIT:
thanks to jordanm I found that indeed there is a memory issue... dmesg gives

```
[127692.401983] Out of memory: Kill process 29035 (python) score 307 or sacrifice child
[127692.401984] Killed process 29035 (python) total-vm:1735776kB, anon-rss:1281708kB, file-rss:0kB
[127693.132028] INFO: rcu_sched detected stalls on CPUs/tasks: {} (detected by 0, t=6045672 jiffies, g=3187114, c=3187113, q=0)
[127693.132028] INFO: Stall ended before state dump start
```

Does anybody know how use less memory to parse an xml file? I am a bit puzzled that the gzip command seems to cause the error?

Comment: "Killed" indicates `SIGKILL`, usually invoked by the kernel for memory reasons. Check `dmesg` if you are on Linux.

Comment: thanks you are right... see edits above... do you know what the best approach would be to deal with this? Is this caused by mem leaks in my code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python memory leaks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435415/python-memory-leaks)

Comment: @carl you should post your edit about `dmesg` as an answer instead and accept it when you can - that is the answer to the title question.

Comment: A more specific candidate for further diagnostics: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24126299/running-out-of-memory-using-python-elementtree .

Comment: specifically: you don't `del citation`. Make sure `write_to_db` doesn't save references to something from the tree other than simple data that doesn't link to anything.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on advice given by ivan_pozdeev and jordanm. First of all the killed command was caused by a memory leak. I managed to monitor the memory with the approach described here

[Total memory used by Python process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938733/total-memory-used-by-python-process)

and I included heaps of del commands to delete every reference to the tree in write_to_db(). I do not understand why the garbage collector doesn't manage that itself, but it seem to do the trick.